# 301 redirect when parts of URL are missing

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, indexing

Could someone please help me with a rule that I cant get to work!

One type of normal URLs are like below:

www.domain.com/a/Inner_music/id/22064

www.domain.com/a/Vowel_length/id/1969733

www.domain.com/a/The_Mind/id/221078

for some reason Google has picked up URLs like the ones below:

www.domain.com/a/Inner_music

www.domain.com/a/Vowel_length

www.domain.com/a/The_Mind

I want to redirect the latter ones that in the URL are 
1) having /a/ 
2) but is missing the last two parts; /id/999999 to the top page /.

Note that urls like below should not be affected:

www.domain.com/inner_music

www.domain.com/vowel_length

The rules I have tried is either redirecting both types or the wrong one:

```
#RedirectMatch 301 ^/a/(.*) /
#RedirectMatch 301 ^/a/(.*)$ /
#RedirectMatch 301 ^/a/(.*)/$ /
#RedirectMatch 301 ^/a/(.*)/ /
```

I have also tried this one but it affect also "good" pages:

```
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/a/.+$
#RewriteRule !^/a/id/.+$ /b/ [R=404,L]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might try:

```
#RedirectMatch 301 ^/a/[^/]*$ /
```

Comment: One more question!

How would it look if I want to have a 404 instead of 301?

Ie, how can this #RedirectMatch 301 ^/a/[^/]*$ / be turned into a 404?

Thanks again!

Comment: Changing 301 to 404 would be worth a try wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, but the URL don't trigger that. The system allows the erroneous URLs which is causing duplicate pages (I am not a programmer so I can't fix it that way). Making www.domain.com/a/Inner_music to be redirected is great, but it may probably be better to give a 404 instead.

Comment: As per apache doc http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect you can use any status code. RTFM